# Unexpected getnameinfo() hostname

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have used C code to get hostname from IPv6 address, using `getnameinfo` api. It returns 0 as success, but the dest string is "empty". Not sure where the mistake is.

```
error_info = getnameinfo(who, wholen, host, NI_MAXHOST, serv, NI_MAXSERV, NI_NOFQDN);

if(error_info){
    fprintf(stderr, "\ngetnameinfo is success.");
    fprintf(stderr, "\nstring @ host :: %s and serv :: %s", host, serv);
}
```

Output:

```
getnameinfo is success.
string @ host :: and serv ::
```

Comment: As per `man page` of `getnameinfo` it will return `0` on success then why you print string for non zero case `if(error_info){...}`? can you print return value as well? Also assume you may pass proper Pointer to hostname string.And print host and service by `*host` and `*serv`.

Comment: You might like to change `if(error_info){` to be `if(!error_info){`and retest.

Answer (score -1):

IP to host name requires an entry for reverse DNS in the DNS server. Here, for the ip address provided there is no reverse DNS available so it has return success with a NULL entry. Check with other host names with reverse DNS entries.